# Need regex to format file in php

Tags: java, php, regex

I have a java file that I want to post online. I am using php to format the file.

Does anyone know the regex to turn the comments blue?

INPUT:

```
/*****
*This is the part 
*I want to turn blue
*for my class
*******************/
class MyClass{
  String s;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use a solution like http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ or http://qbnz.com/highlighter/? You'd not have to reinvent the wheel. =)

Answer (score 1):

Naiive version:

```
$formatted = preg_replace('|(/\*.*?\*/)|m', '<span class="blue">$1</span>', $java_code_here);
```

... not tested, YMMV, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you won't be able to parse specific parts of a Java file using only regular expressions - Java is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). If your file has additional structure (such as "it always begins with a comment followed by a newline, followed by a class definition"), you can generate a regular expression for such a case. For instance, you'd match `/\*+(.*?)\*+/$`, where `.` is assumed to match multiple lines, and `$` matches the end of a line.

In general, to make a regex work, you first define what patterns you want to find (rigorously, but in spoken language), and then translate that to standard regular expression notation.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A regex that can parse simple quotes should be able to find comments in C/C++ style languages.
I assume Java is of that type.

This is a Perl faq sample by someone else, although I added the part about // style comments (with or without line continuation) and reformated.

It basically does a global search and replace. Data is replaced verbatim if non a comment, otherwise replace the comment with your color formatting tags.

You should be able to adapt this to php, and it is expanded for clarity (maybe too much clarity though).

```
s{
   ## Comments, group 1:
    (
        /\*         ##  Start of /* ... */ comment
        [^*]*\*+    ##  Non-* followed by 1-or-more *'s
        (?:
            [^/*][^*]*\*+
        )*          ##  0-or-more things which don't start with /
                    ##    but do end with '*'
        /           ##  End of /* ... */ comment

      |  
        //          ## Start of // ... comment
        (?:
            [^\\]         ## Any Non-Continuation character ^\
          |               ##   OR
            \\\n?         ## Any Continuation character followed by 0-1 newline \n

         )*?            ## To be done 0-many times, stopping at the first end of comment

         \n         ##  End of // comment
    )

 | ##  OR,  various things which aren't comments, group 2:
    (
        " (?: \\. | [^"\\] )* "  ## Double quoted text
      |

        ' (?: \\. | [^'\\] )* '  ## Single quoted text
      |
        .           ##  Any other char
        [^/"'\\]*   ##  Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape
    )               ##    or continuation (escape + newline)
 }
 {defined $2 ? $2 : "<some color>$1</some color>"}gxse;
```